# Autofac, accessing ContainerBuilder from random component

Tags: autofac

I am playing with Autofac and let's pretend i have a component (DLL) in my application that is using Logging. How and where to log will be defined by main App. So it registers ILog interface with Autofac.

Problem is how my component can get access to ContainerBuilder object to resolve ILog?

I can always initialize my component with IContainer but that defeats the purpose. I would just pass ILog interface to component instead of IContainer.

Comment: How you do register an implementation of `ILog` with `Autofac`? Usually you should be able to just inject an instance of `ILog` into any component. Please provide some registration code.

Comment: @alsami not even sure what you asking. My Main() method of the App registers all components.

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<SomeType>().As<ILog>();

I just wish all other objects in my application  (even if they are not registered in Autofac)  could resolve ILog now.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand where you are with this correctly - it's worth reading up on the "Composition Root" for how to think about this in general. The short answer is "you don't access `Container`s from components."

https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/

As you say, your component shouldn't know anything about Autofac - that actually goes for all of your code except a small section in your main application. So how does the ILog find its way to your component? From that Mark Seemann post:

*"This means that all the application code relies solely on Constructor Injection"*

That's a good general rule to make your code cleaner, even if you weren't using a DI framework. So in your situation, say you have a very simple app like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var component = new Component();    // we want logging to happen inside here
        component.DoStuff();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

You actually just want to add your `ILog` as a dependency on your `Component` and then inject that as close as possible to your app-entry point:

```
public class Component
{
    private readonly ILog _logger;

    public Component(ILog logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        _logger.Log("this is a test");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = GetContainer();
        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())  
        {
            var test = scope.Resolve<Component>();          // this is potentially the only place we need to resolve anything
            test.DoStuff();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static IContainer GetContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<Component>();
        builder.RegisterType<Logger>()
            .As<ILog>();
        var container = builder.Build();
        return container;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what you have wrote is a common consensus on internet. After some research turned out what i am looking for is called "Service Locator" which is considered to be an anti-pattern.

Comment: I am not sold (yet) that "Service Locator" is a bad guy and believe it has it's use when components are used in-house and documented. But thanks for your answer and i "tried" to up-vote it. Turned out i do not have enough karma for it to be visible.

Comment: Yep, there are a lot of technical reasons why Service Locator is considered an anti-pattern, e.g. https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/. From personal experience, even a well managed service locator can lead to a world of problems once you try to re-use components or access them from different app-entry points - including unit testing. Using constructor injection *everywhere* might superficially make your classes a bit bigger but the benefits you get from extracting dependencies means you're extremely unlikely to regret it in the long run.

Comment: @George Service-Locator is definitely an anti-pattern. You should never resolve something manually outside of `public static void Main(string[] args)` delegate.